# GetOwinContext in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

I am using [Membership Reboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) in my Asp.Net5 MVC 6 web application to manage my identity, logins etc.

I'm trying to get MR's [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/master/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot.Owin/OwinAuthenticationService.cs) working as an implementation for the `IAuthenticationService` interface which I am dependency injecting into my controllers.

The sample for this involves injecting the `IAuthenticationService` depending using the following Autofac registration:

```
builder.Register(ctx=>HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()).As<IOwinContext>();
builder.Register<IAuthenticationService>(ctx =>
{
    var owin = ctx.Resolve<IOwinContext>();
    return new OwinAuthenticationService(
        MembershipRebootOwinConstants.AuthenticationType,
        ctx.Resolve<IUserAccountService>(),
        owin.Environment);
}).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In MVC5, that would be fine as `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()` as an extension method in the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` assembly. However, this assembly is no longer used in MVC6 and so `HttpContext.Current` does not resolve.

I've seen that the new way of accessing `HttpContext` is using the new `IHttpContextAccessor` interface, but this doesn't solve the problem of getting the Owin context.

Is there a way to get the current Owin context in MVC6, or the the current Owin environment dictionary (since that's what the `OwinAuthenticationService` class uses)?

Comment: I am working on some authentication that works with Owin and is not supported yet in the new ASP.NET Core world and am running into the same problem. Did you find any way to get the old working with the new? I can't get my signout to trigger with what is configured in an Owin context at startup from the controller without access to the Owin context.

Comment: I have the same issue. I need an Owin context to actually SignOut user. Any workaround_

Answer (score 0):

OWIN lost its position in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (aka ASP.NET 5),

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/owin.html

But you can find all the information on the above page. It seems the OWIN context is gone.